# jQuery get id from dropdown list not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get id from dropdown list but my code isn't work

```
 $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);

});
```

Here is dropdown code

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li id='1'><a href="#contains">น้อยมาก</a></li>
  <li id='2'><a href="#its_equal">น้อย</a></li>
  <li id='3'><a href="#greather_than">ปานกลาง </a></li>
  <li id='4'><a href="#less_than">นิยม  </a></li>
  <li id='5'><a href="#all">นิยมมาก</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use jquery each loop to get all the id of child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<a>` doesn't have an `id`, only the `<li>` has. Use:

```
alert(this.parentNode.id);
```

Here, `this` refers to `<a>` and not the `<li>`.

Comment: ok it alert but if i am try to $dad =(this.parentNode.id);  why $dad=NaN

Comment: @Danusorn Where are you using the code? `this` is very powerful. Have to use with care. Show full code where you get NaN.

Comment: little problem i need to get id from li and add to redirect url do you have any idea

Comment: @Danusorn Like this: `location.href = '/redirect/' + this.parentNode.id;`?

Comment: ok fine but if  i have two var to redirect like 
location.href = '/redirect/' + this.parentNode.id/+othervar  how it work

Comment: @Danusorn Yes, that's the way... `location.href = '/redirect/' + this.parentNode.id + '/' +othervar;`

Comment: @Danusorn Can you please use `location.href` instead of `window.location`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(this).parent().attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

first suggestion :- a tag does not contain any id so if you are going to fetch id it will return null.
second suggestion :- event was not binding properly.

lets try this one

```
 $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $(".dropdown-menu > li > a").click(function(e) {
        alert(this.parentElement.id);
        e.preventDefault();
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");;
         var concept = $(this).text();
         $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
         $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);

       });
     });
```

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/z2waxz81/1/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `id` of the `<li>` tag or are you referring to to the `href` attribute? Your code doesn't seem to be using the `id` anywhere.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li id='1'><a href="#contains">น้อยมาก</a></li>
    <li id='2'><a href="#its_equal">น้อย</a></li>
    <li id='3'><a href="#greather_than">ปานกลาง </a></li>
    <li id='4'><a href="#less_than">นิยม  </a></li>
    <li id='5'><a href="#all">นิยมมาก</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    alert(this.id); // undefined -> this refers to the <a> tag but you don't seem to use an id anywhere?
    e.preventDefault();

    var $a = $(this);
    var $li = $a.parent('li');
    console.log($li.attr('id')); // this will log the parent `id`

    var param = $a.attr('href').replace('#', ''); // get the href attribute from the <a> tag and remove the pound symbol
    var concept = $a.text(); // get the text content of the <a> tag

    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to process anchor tag or li tag

```
$('div').each(function (index, value) { 
    $(this + ' > a').click(function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr());
    });// if you want to process the anchor tag
    $(this + ' > li').click(function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr());
    });// if you want to process the li tag
});
```